# How to check if a list of ids or objects matches a many to many record in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Result(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
```

Given that I have a list of ids for the Answer model, like this:

```
answer_list = [1, 3, 5, 16]
```

Is there a way to get a Result instance in which the answers field contains all of the ids in answer_list? I am not looking for an exact match to the items in the field, but all answer ids need to exist.

I have tried the following solution but it looks for an exact match:

```
query = Result.objects.filter(answers__in=answers).annotate(num_answers=Count('answers'))
result = query.filter(num_answers=len(answers)).first()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this with repeated filter calls:

```
query = Result.objects.all()
for answer in answer_list:
    query = query.filter(answers=answer)
```